# if I destructure an object and change its value, will the value remain in the enclosing object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

So I'm destructuring an existing array from `this.props` object. My questions is if I alter the declared variable, will the array change in the object `this.props`?

```
let { playlistTracks } = this.props;
let id = track.id;
for (let track in playlistTracks) {
  if (track.id === id) {
    return;
  }
}  
playlistTracks.push(track);
```

I expect that `this.state.playlistTracks` will have another track pushed into it

Comment: You're **destructuring** an object `this.props`, this is not a _destructor_.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide additional code to demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish? For instance, `track` does not appear to be in scope in the example you provided.

Comment: Note that `for ... in` loops through the *keys* of an object, not the values.

Comment: You may be interested in reading more about [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the array will be mutated because you are looping through it and using the .push() method.